# Printing the search path taken to find item during BFS

Tags: perl, breadth-first-search

I am trying to solve the doublets puzzle problem using Perl. This is one of my first times using Perl so please excuse the messy code.

I have everything working, I believe, but am having an issue printing the shortest path. Using a queue and BFS I am able to find the target word but not the actual path taken.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have been told to keep track of the parents of each element but it is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $file = 'test';
#my $file = 'wordlist';
open(my $fh, $file);
my $len = length($ARGV[0]);
my $source = $ARGV[0];
my $target = $ARGV[1];
my @words;

# Creates new array of correct length words
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    my $rowlen = length($row);
    if ($rowlen == $len) {    
        push @words, $row;
    }
}

my %wordHash;

# Creates graph for word variations using dictionary
foreach my $word (@words) {
    my $wordArr = [];
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

        my $begin = substr($word, 0, $i);
        my $end = substr($word, $i+1, $len);
        my $key = "$begin" . "_" . "$end";
        my $Arr = [];

        my $regex = "$begin" . "[a-z]" . "$end";
        foreach my $wordTest (@words) {
            if ("$wordTest" =~ $regex && "$wordTest" ne "$word") {
                push $wordArr, "$wordTest";
            }
        }
    }

    $wordHash{"$word"} = $wordArr;
}

my @queue;
push(@queue, "$source");
my $next = $source;
my %visited;
my %parents;
my @path;

# Finds path using BFS and Queue
while ("$next" ne "$target") {

    print "$next: ";
    foreach my $variation (@{$wordHash{$next}}) {
        push(@queue, "$variation"); 
        $parents{"$variation"} = $next;
        print "$variation | ";
    }

    print "\n-----------------\n";

    $visited{"$next"} = 1;
    push(@path, "$next");

    $next = shift(@queue);

    while ($visited{"$next"} == 1) {
        $next = shift(@queue);   
    }

}

print "FOUND: $next\n\n";

print "Path the BFS took: ";
print "@path\n\n";

print "Value -> Parent: \n";

for my $key (keys %parents) {
   print "$key -> $parents{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: What does your source data look like?  What would be a typical invocation of your script?

Comment: I try it with source "word" and target "wore" and it doesn't seem to find the shortest path...or the actual target; I get "Path the BFS took: word cord ford lord ward wood"

Comment: Doublets puzzle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder

Comment: Could you update your question with an example failure?  Is it not printing the path taken at all?  Or, not a correct path?  Or, not the shortest path?

Answer (score 0):

Before you accept a word from the `@queue` to be `$next`, you test to ensure that it's not been `%visited`.  By then, though, damage has been done.  The test has ensured a visited word wont become the focus again and hence, will prevent loops but the earlier code updated `%parents` whether the word had been `%visited` or not.

If a word has been `%visited`, you not only want to avoid it becomming the `$next` candidate, you want to avoid it being a considered `$variation` as that will screw up `%parents`.  I don't have a word dictionary to test with and you haven't given an example of the failure but I think you can fix this up by shifting the `%visited` guard into the inner loop where variations are considered;

```
foreach my $variation (@{$wordHash{$next}}) {
    next if %visited{ $variation } ;
    push(@queue, "$variation"); 
    ... etc ...
```

This will protect the integrity of your `@parents` array as well as stop loops.  On a small note, you don't need use double quotes when indexing into a hash; as I've done above, just state the scalar variable - using quotes just interpolates the value of the variable which produces the same result.

Your code, IMHO, is excellent for a beginner, BTW.

### Update

I've since got a word dictionary and the problem above does exists as well as one other.  The code does move one letter at a time from the source but in a near random direction - not necessarily closer to the target.  To correct that, I changed the regex you use to build your graph such that the corresponding letter from the target replaces the generic `[a-z]`.  There are also a couple of minor changes - mostly style related.  The updated code looks like this;

```
use v5.12;

my $file = 'wordlist.txt';
#my $file = 'wordlist';
open(my $fh, $file);
my $len = length($ARGV[0]);
my $source = $ARGV[0];
my $target = $ARGV[1];
chomp $target;
my @target = split('', $target);
my @words;

# Creates new array of correct length words
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    $row =~ s/[\r\n]+$//;
    my $rowlen = length($row);
    if ($rowlen == $len) {
        push @words, $row;
    }
}

my %wordHash;

# Creates graph for word variations using dictionary
foreach my $word (@words) {
    my $wordArr = [];
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

        my $begin = substr($word, 0, $i);
        my $end = substr($word, $i+1, $len);
        my $key = "$begin" . "_" . "$end";
        my $Arr = [];

        # my $re_str = "$begin[a-z]$end";
        my $regex = $begin . $target[$i] . $end ;
        foreach my $wordTest (@words) {
            if ($wordTest =~ / ^ $regex $ /x ) {
                next if $wordTest eq $word ;
                push $wordArr, "$wordTest";
            }
        }
    }

    $wordHash{"$word"} = $wordArr;
}

my @queue;
push(@queue, "$source");
my $next = $source;
my %visited;
my %parents;
my @path;

# Finds path using BFS and Queue
while ($next ne $target) {

    print "$next: ";
    $visited{$next} = 1;
    foreach my $variation (@{$wordHash{$next}}) {
        next if $visited{ $variation } ;
        push(@queue, $variation);
        $parents{$variation} = $next;
        print "$variation | ";
    }

    print "\n-----------------\n";

    push(@path, $next);

    while ( $visited{$next} )  {
      $next = shift @queue ;
    }
}
push @path, $target ;

print "FOUND: $next\n\n";

print "Path the BFS took: @path\n\n";

print "Value -> Parent: \n";

for my $key (keys %parents) {
   print "$key -> $parents{$key}\n";
}
```

and when ran produces;

```
./words.pl head tail | more
head: heal |
-----------------
heal: teal | heil |
-----------------
teal:
-----------------
heil: hail |
-----------------
hail: tail |
-----------------
FOUND: tail

Path the BFS took: head heal teal heil hail tail

Value -> Parent:
hail -> heil
heil -> heal
teal -> heal
tail -> hail
heal -> head
```

You could probably remove the printing of the %parents hash - as hash values come out randomly, it doesnt tell you much